# Add AnswerFormatRegex constraint to Mechanical Turk item using BOTO

Tags: python, boto, mechanicalturk

I am trying to create some automated HIT's in Amazon Mechanical Turk using boto and am interested in adding an AnswerFormatRegex restriction to a question. How can this constraint be added to a question? A snippet of how I am coding the questions is below.

```
from boto.mturk.connection import MTurkConnection
from boto.mturk.question import QuestionContent,Question,QuestionForm, 
Overview,AnswerSpecification,SelectionAnswer,FormattedContent,FreeTextAnswer

### JUMPING TO RELEVANT CODE ###

qc1 = QuestionContent()
qc1.append_field('Title','Question 1')

fta1 = FreeTextAnswer(num_lines=1)

q1 = Question(identifier="question1",
              content=qc1,
              answer_spec=AnswerSpecification(fta1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question but I was able to wrap my head around it finally. Here's what I used that seems to be working:

```
qc1 = QuestionContent()
qc1.append_field('Title','DATE:')

constraints1 = [RegExConstraint("***REGEX HERE****",
                                error_text="ERROR.",
                                flags='i')]

fta1 = FreeTextAnswer(constraints=constraints, default="", num_lines=1)

q1 = Question(identifier="date",
              content=qc1,
              answer_spec=AnswerSpecification(fta1))
```